# Error running tests on a Play Project in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, playframework-2.0

I've setup my play project in jenkins using the sbt plugin.

The project compiles fine but the tests fail when i use the sbt laucher. The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

if i use "activator test" all tests run fine but with the sbt fails.

The project is a Play Java Project. Anyone knows what the problem is? is the sbt plugin the best way to integrate play in jenkins?